Are there any containers that can be pushed side-by-side by pistons?
So I am building a factory that produces items. I want the be able to fill a whole box of items before it gets "Shipped". I want to make a row of boxes that get pushed by pistons when the box under a hopper gets filled.
The problem is, the pistons won't push a chest next to another one, because of the "two chests side by side makes on large chest" rule. This also goes for Trapped chests. When I use a shulker container, the pistons break them. How can I push containers side by side?
I am playing Minecraft: Wii U Edition with Patch 43, the last update to the Wii U version.

Turns out that a regular chest and a trapped chest can be placed next to each other and can be pushed by a piston. And that leads to another issue now.
